# Set Flash Builder 4.5 mobile application TextArea background color to black and font color to white

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5, flex-mobile, flash-builder4.5

I am creating a dummy mobile application in Flash Builder 4.5. In application code I am using a TextArea and I am adding and removing TextArea on rum time. Now I want to set TextArea  background color to black and font color to white.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I must say it's not really straightforward, but the style you're looking for is not `backgroundColor`, but [contentBackgroundColor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#styleSummary). It is applicable to all components extending [SkinnableTextBase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html).

```
<s:TextArea color="0xffffff" contentBackgroundColor="0x000000" />
```